# Laravel integration testing jobs

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-queue

I am trying to run an integration tests for my app. I have those jobs:

- StartJob
- PrepareJob
- PeformJob

StartJob dispatches one or more PrepareJob, every PrepareJob dispatches one PerformJob.

Adding this

```
$this->expectsJobs(
        [
            StartJobs::class,
            PrepareJob::class,
            PerformJob::class
        ]
    );
```

makes my test fail with error saying

```
1) JobsTest::testJobs
BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0_Illuminate_Contracts_Bus_Dispatcher::dispatchNow() does not exist on this mock object
```

Removing $this->expectsJobs makes all my tests pass, but I can't assert a given job was run, only whether it modified the DB to a given state.

StartJobs.php

```
    class StartJobs extends Job implements ShouldQueue
    {
        use InteractsWithQueue;
        use DispatchesJobs;

        public function handle(Writer $writer)
        {
            $writer->info("[StartJob] Started");

            for($i=0; $i < 5; $i++)
            {
                $this->dispatch(new PrepareJob());
            }

            $this->delete();
        }

    }
```

PrepareJob.php

```
class PrepareJob  extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use DispatchesJobs;

    public function handle(Writer $writer)
    {
        $writer->info("[PrepareJob] Started");

        $this->dispatch(new PerformJob());

        $this->delete();
    }

}
```

PerformJob.php

```
class PerformJob  extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public function handle(Writer $writer)
    {
        $writer->info("[PerformJob] Started");

        $this->delete();
    }
}
```

JobsTest.php

```
class JobsTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var Dispatcher
     */
    protected $dispatcher;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->dispatcher = $this->app->make(Dispatcher::class);
    }

    public function testJobs()
    {
        $this->expectsJobs(
            [
                StartJobs::class,
                PrepareJob::class,
                PerformJob::class
            ]
        );

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(new StartJobs());
    }
}
```

I think it has to do something with how I am using a concrete dispatcher, while $this->expectsJob mocks the dispatcher. Might be related to this - https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/207. What's the way to solve this?

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: @AngadDubey I thought the code was so simplistic there was no point in posting it. But while I've been writing simple jobs and test, I found the root of the problem. I modified my post with all the code samples and observations

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like there is no dispatchNow()-method. In the Jobs your run dispatch() but the error says dispatchNow() does not exist.

Laravel didn't have the dispatchNow()-method before a certain version (i think Laravel 5.2 ... not sure) but just the dispatch(). Could be that the expectsJobs didn't think about that and fails.

You could try not passing it in one array but use 3 commands:

```
$this->expectsJobs(StartJobs::class);
$this->expectsJobs(PrepareJob::class);
$this->expectsJobs(PerformJob::class);
```

Maybe that helps.